# Build splitter.pyx (and splitter.pxd, from tree folder) using Cython on Sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, cython

Its probably a simple question, but I'm having some trouble on building the _splitter.pyx into _splitter.so (so I can try some changes I made). Right now I'm trying to build the original file with the command:

> cython -a _splitter.pyx

And it generates the following error:

> ### Error compiling Cython file:
>
> ...
>                                            self.index_to_samples,
>                                            self.feature_values,
>                                            end_negative, start_positive)
>
> cdef int compare_SIZE_t(const void* a, const void* b) nogil:
>
> ### ^
>
> _splitter.pyx:1008:34: Expected ')', found '*'

I tried some changes like:

> cython -3 _splitter.pyx

or

> cython -a _splitter.pyx _splitter.pxd

But it only generated more errors. Am I doing something wrong?

When its fixed, I plan to use the command:

> gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/python2.7 -o _splitter.so _splitter.c

Is it the correct approach?

Thanks a lot for the help

EDIT:
Upgraded my Cython to 0.24 version. Now I get the following error in several lines:

> ### Error compiling Cython file:
>
> ...
>                      features[f_i], features[f_j] = features[f_j], features[f_i]
>
> # Draw a random threshold
>   current.threshold = rand_uniform(min_feature_value,
>   max_feature_value,
>   random_state)
>
> ### ^
>
> _splitter.pyx:1547:65: Converting to Python object not allowed without gil

Comment: Looks like a syntax error, maybe a missing `)` on an earlier line.  We need to see more of the code (around the error).

Comment: I just copied the original file from github:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_splitter.pyx
The error is on line 1008 of this file

Comment: I cloned the whole scikit-learn repository and run `cython _splitter.pyx` without problems (cython 0.24.1, any version >= 0.23 should be ok)

Comment: You are right. When I cloned the repository, it worked. I was using a copy of my sklearn folder to do it, and it didnt work well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading your Cython installation. Old versions (< 0.18) do not support const keyword.

See [how do I use const](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-const)

> Answer: Since Cython 0.18, you can just use it in your code and in
>   your declarations.
>
> Earlier versions of Cython did not support const directly and required
>   the following hack to compile it into the C source code:

Comment: I upgraded it to 0.24, but I'm getting lots of new errors now, that are basically the same:
"Converting to Python object not allowed without gil"
Its happening in several lines

Comment: The exception is telling you exactly what the problem is: you're trying to create a Python obect in a function you have defined as `nogil`.